# Upright freezer sliding on tiled floor

Tags: freezer

My upright freezer has 2 rollers/wheels at the back and 2 plastic screw legs at the front. I have a tiled floor and the suction of the door is too strong, the whole thing just slides forward when I try to open it. I tried all the suggestions I saw here for similar situations and on other sites. Rubber wedges and rubber stoppers didn't work. The freezer is about 6 ft tall, the wheels on the back are very convenient for moving it about but they don't help once it is in place. I resorted to using silicone, I put 4 large blobs on the floor and rolled it on to them. When in place, I built up the silicone around the front legs so it touched the under side and formed a wedge around the legs. Let it sit until it goes off and it worked.

Comment: I think you should break this up to the question and answer.  Question dealing with the problem and a separate answer on how you fixed it.  You can answer your own question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would have just put it on a piece of rug/carpet with a non-skid rubber backing.

Answer (score 1):

*Taking the original post as "here is how I solved it, is there a better way?"*

Put the whole thing up on blocks. Two pieces of 2x4, cut to the width of the freezer should do the job. Position one just to the front of the rear wheels and the other just behind the front legs.